# Using useEffect hook with "async"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks, next.js

How to clean up react request in react hooks. I read that in need to enter in my hook AbortController but I don't know how. I using next.js. What are best methods to eliminate this problem ? And I get this warning:

> Warning: can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

This is my custom hook to fetch data:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { MOVIE_API_URL, MOVIE_KEY } from '../../config'

export const useMovieDetailsFetch = (movieId) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    setError(false)
    setLoading(true)

    try {
      const movieDetailsEndpoint = `${MOVIE_API_URL}movie/${movieId}?api_key=${MOVIE_KEY}`
      const result = await (await fetch(movieDetailsEndpoint)).json()
      const creditsEndpoint = `${MOVIE_API_URL}movie/${movieId}/credits?api_key=${MOVIE_KEY}`
      const creditsResult = await (await fetch(creditsEndpoint)).json()
      // Filtring in crew for directors only
      const movieDirectors = creditsResult.crew.filter(
        (member) => member.job === 'Director'
      )

      setState({
        ...result,
        movieDirectors,
        actors: creditsResult.cast,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      setError(true)
    }
    setLoading(false)
  }, [movieId])

  useEffect(() => {
   
    fetchData()
  }, [fetchData])

  return [state, loading, error]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an [abort controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort), in its rawest form:

```
const controller = new AbortController();
const { signal } = controller;
...

fetch(url, { signal });

...
// abort
controller.abort();
```

To abort an in-flight `fetch` in effect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const { signal } = controller;
  fetch(url, { signal });

  return () => {
    controller.abort(); // abort on unmount for cleanup
  };
}, []);
```

I found this [article](https://itnext.io/how-you-can-abort-fetch-request-on-a-flight-830a639b9b92) very informative when I needed to develop a way to cancel fetch requests.

**Edit**

The `signal` needs to be added to the `fetch` requests options object. You can also define the `async fetchData` function inside the effect (this is normal), so it's all enclosed in the effect hook's callback scope.

```
export const useMovieDetailsFetch = (movieId) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setError(false);
      setLoading(true);

      try {
        const movieDetailsEndpoint = `${MOVIE_API_URL}movie/${movieId}?api_key=${MOVIE_KEY}`;
        const result = await (
            await fetch(movieDetailsEndpoint, { signal })
          ).json();
        const creditsEndpoint = `${MOVIE_API_URL}movie/${movieId}/credits?api_key=${MOVIE_KEY}`;
        const creditsResult = await (
            await fetch(creditsEndpoint, { signal })
          ).json();
        // Filtring in crew for directors only
        const movieDirectors = creditsResult.crew.filter(
          (member) => member.job === 'Director'
        );

        setState({
          ...result,
          movieDirectors,
          actors: creditsResult.cast,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    }

    fetchData();

    return () => controller.abort();
  }, [movieId]);

  return [state, loading, error];
}
```

Comment: i enter this to this hook ,but it still doesnt work        ` useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const { signal } = controller
    fetchData({ signal })

    return () => {
      controller.abort()
    }
  }, [fetchData])`

Comment: @KubaKluzniak The signal needs to be passed to the `fetch` function's options parameter. Updated my answer with a suggested solution.